# Type ‘()’ cannot conform to ‘AccessibilityRotorContent’

Tags: swiftui

Driving me nuts… I have a class called TrackPiece2 with a bunch of var’s in it… I have an array of these and I want to change a value in each TrackPiece2 of the array…
but I am getting the error “Type ‘()’ cannot conform to ‘AccessibilityRotorContent’” on the ForEach line of func changeZoom below

```
class TrackPiece2: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var centerPnt: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var radius: CGFloat = 0.0
    var width: CGFloat = 0.0
    var startAngle: Angle = Angle.zero
    var angleArc: Angle = Angle.zero
    var color: Color = Color.clear
    var zoom: CGFloat = 1.0
.
.
.
```

```
class TrackLayout2 {
    var trackPieces: [TrackPiece2] = []
    var drawOuterLines: Bool = false
    
    func addTrackPiece(newTrkPc: TrackPiece2) {
        self.trackPieces.append(newTrkPc)
    }
    
    func changeZoom(newZoom: CGFloat) {
        ForEach(trackPieces) {    <——— Error occurs here
            trkPc in
            trkPc.zoom = newZoom
        }
    }
    
    func loadTrackPieces() {
        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: 160, y:160)
        
        addTrackPiece(newTrkPc: TrackPiece2(centerPnt: centerPoint, radius: 160.0, width: 10.0, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), angleArc: Angle(degrees: 45), color: Color.pink, zoom: 0.5))
    }
}
```

Interesting… but if I replace the entire ForEach {} in func changeZoom with a specific member of the array, ‘trackPieces[0].zoom = newZoom’, it works fine…

Also, TrackPiece2 is Identifiable… I also made it Hashable as well… but that didn’t change anything so I left it as Identifiable only

Thanks for any advice/help… TJ

Comment: `ForEach` with capital F belongs to the rendering area of a SwiftUI `View`. A class is the wrong place.

Answer (score 16):

Ugh ! Thanks vadian… changing

```
ForEach(trackPieces) {
            trkPc in
```

to

```
for trkPc in trackPieces {
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: we can you it as trackPieces.forEach { trkPc in
this should work